# Script running on multiple sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-apps-script-editor

I'm trying to automatically create a timestamp beside the cell I've edited, but for some reason the timestamp is being created on a second sheet as well. So when I edit a cell on the first sheet (titled 'Season 8), it will create a timestamp on the cell beside it, but also create that timestamp on the next sheet as well (titled 'Alt - Season 8'). Only these two sheets seem to be related, as the timestamps don't get created on any of the other sheets in the doc. I've created a gif to show what the problem is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0s81R.jpg

Here's the code:

```
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); //shortcut to access ui methods
var ps = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); //shortcut to access properties methods
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() //shortcut to access spreadsheet methods

var timezone = "PST8PDT";
var timestampFormat = "h:mm a, yyyy-MM-dd"; // Timestamp Format (hour:minute, AM/PM, year-month-day)

function timestamp(currentSheet){
  var updateColName = 'Result' //the name of the column we're looking for
  var timestampColName = 'Date' //the name of the column where the timestamp will go
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
  Logger.log(sheet.getName())

  var actRng = sheet.getActiveRange(); //finding the active range of the selected cell
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn(); //finding the column of the active cell (returns int, start at index 1)
  var editRow = actRng.getRow(); //finding the row of the active cell

  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(); //return an array with an element for the value of each cell in the first row (header row)
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timestampColName, editColumn); //finding the index of the first column after editColumn with the name of timeStampColName (index starts from 0)

  var editColumnName = sheet.getRange(1, editColumn).getValue() //finding the name of the column of the active cell
  if (dateCol > -1 && editRow > 12 && editColumnName == updateColName){ //if: a column with name timestmapColName exists, and if row is below 12, and if the name of the column of the active cell matches the name we are looking for (updateColName), create the timestamp
    var cell = sheet.getRange(editRow, dateCol + 1) //defining which cell the timestamp will go in. We do dateCol + 1 since dateCol starts from index 0, but getRange starts at index 1
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestampFormat); //storing our date format in date
    cell.setValue(date); //setting the value of the cell to date (our timestamp)
  }

  Logger.log('first column with header \'Date\': %s', dateCol + 1) //we add 1 to start from index 1 to compare against editColumn which starts at index 1
  Logger.log('column with active cell: %s', editColumn)
  Logger.log('column name of active cell: %s', editColumnName)
  Logger.log('Column name we need to match: %s', updateColName)

}

function onEdit(){
  timestamp()
}
```

There are no script or user properties.

EDIT: I've got some updates which completely baffle my mind. My theory that the two were sheets were linked somehow since the second one was made using the 'Make a copy' button was completely wrong, as I have found with some more testing that as long as the cells are lined up correctly (column spacing), then any timestamp will be created on the active sheet (as it should) and also on *any* sheet named 'Season 8' as long as the column spacing is correct. Even if the sheet called Season 8 is a completely brand new sheet, the timestamp will still be created. I have no idea what's causing this and would like to find out, as my current fix is just renaming the sheet to something else.

Comment: If you rewrite your function to use the [edit event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit), do you still get this issue? Are there any other users who may have installed triggers? (You'll have to ask them to check, because you can't view others' triggers)

Comment: @tehhowch There aren't any other users with access to the sheet so no other triggers. The event object also didn't work when I tried it, but that could be because I don't really understand how to use it properly. As for other updates, I have tried creating other sheets and for some reason, the timestamp will be created on the active sheet as well as the 'Season 8' sheet as long as column spacing is correct. At first, I believed the problem was that the two sheets were somehow linked since the second one was created using the 'Make a copy' button, but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: are there any other functions in your project that use the text `Season 8`? You can use Ctrl+F to search through all files in your script project.

Comment: The term `Season` doesn't even appear anywhere, the only place I could think of it appearing is that I made a script property with `Season 8` and `Alt - Season 8` as the only two values in it, stored those in an array, then called the timestamp() function with a parameter to pass on the sheet that will be used. But properties don't transfer between project files, and this is a brand new project file, so I don't think it's related.

Comment: It's a completely separate Apps Script Project File.

Comment: Confirmed: I have separate Apps Scripts projects, not just separate .gs code files in the same project.

Comment: please edit your question to include relevant details. I'm assuming at this point you've already opened and checked that the script properties are empty for the new sheet. If so, this is relevant information for your question to include.